# How to reduce the server response time during add multiple records to database in single time?

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to add multiple records at once. I got output but if I try to create a large number of records the browser will takes a long time to respond. How can this code be modified to reduce server time?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>How to insert Multiple records to database using PHP & Mysql -Learn2India.com</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<p>Passanger:
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
</p>
<input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub">
</form>
<?php
// Database Connection

$user_name="root";

$password="";

$database="gobinath";

$server="localhost";

$db_server=mysql_connect("$server","$user_name","$password"); // connect Server

$db_database=mysql_select_db("$database"); // Connect Server

// Generate Multiple Rows Create operation
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
  if($_POST['amount'] >0 )
  {
      ?>
      <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
      <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
      <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>T24</th>
      <th>TIM</th>
      <th>APlus</th>
      </tr>
      <?php
      for($i=1; $i<=$_POST['amount'] ; $i++)
      {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="yname<?php echo $i; ?>" id="yname<?php echo $i; ?>"></td><!--Pass the dynmamic name-->
            <td><input type="email" name="yemail<?php echo $i; ?>" id="yemail<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="yage<?php echo $i; ?>" id="yage<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
        </tr>

        <?php

      }
      ?>
      <tr>
      <td><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $i-1; ?>" name="total" id="total"></td>
      <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" id="summ" name="summ">
      </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
      <?php
  }
}

// Multiple Insert operation
if(isset($_POST['summ']))
{
    $toatal=$_POST['total'];
    if($toatal > 0)
    {
        for($i=1; $i<=$toatal; $i++) {
            $data=mysql_query("insert into minsert values('".$_POST["yname$i"]."', '".$_POST["yemail$i"]."', '".$_POST["yage$i"]."')");
        }
    }
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: improved formatting, grammar

Comment: How many records are we talking? It shouldn't be a problem to add a few hundred records in under a second.

Comment: Search for mysql insert batches. This should give you a start.

Comment: If I'm generate  100+ rows the server takes long time , some time browser also not working

Answer (score 2):

You can run one INSERT statement with multiple rows, like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES
('val1', 'val2', 'val3'),
('val1', 'val2', 'val3'),
('val1', 'val2', 'val3'),
('val1', 'val2', 'val3');
```

If you are inserting really huge amount of lines, it is best to group them in few INSERT statements, each with few hundreds of values.

In result, instead of having 150 000 INSERT statements, you can have 150 INSERT statements, each with 1000 values. Each query have some manage cost, regardless values in the query (time for prepare query, optimize it, manage indexes etc...).